# Disambiguate the [jetstream] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The `jetstream` tag is being used for two separate topics:

1. A Laravel application development kit called [Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/introduction.html) (this is the official use listed in [the tag's wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jetstream/info)).
2. A messaging persistence system called [JetStream](https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/jetstream) which is part of the [NATS.io](https://nats.io/) platform.

There are currently:

- 489 questions matching `[jetstream]` ([search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetstream)).
- 386 questions matching `[jetstream] [laravel]` ([search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetstream+laravel)).
- 37 questions matching `[jetstream] [nats.io]` ([search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetstream+nats.io)).
- 6 questions using `[jetstream]` without a supporting `[laravel-*]` or `[nats.io]` tag ([search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjetstream%5D+-laravel+-nats+-%5Blaravel%5D+-%5Blaravel-8%5D+-%5Blaravel-9%5D+-%5Blaravel-livewire%5D+-%5Bnats.io%5D)). All of these are about the first (Laravel) topic.

Is it possible to disambiguate this tag? Perhaps by splitting into `laravel-jetstream` and `nats.io-jetstream`?

Comment: Given the numbers, the existing tag should be renamed to [laravel-jetstream] and the other questions should be retagged with a new tag.

Comment: @Laurel: Would `jetstream-laravel` and `jetstream-natsio` make it more discoverable?

Comment: @MatthieuM. The canonical name of the thing is "Laravel Jetstream" so the other way around sounds unnatural. As for the other one, I'm not in that ecosystem, but it seems to be called both "NATS JetStream" and "NATS.io Jetstream".

Answer (score 3):

I retagged all the NATS questions with [nats-jetstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nats-jetstream), which seems to be what it's most commonly called. All that's left to do would be to rename [jetstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetstream) to [laravel-jetstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-jetstream) and possibly create [nats.io-jetstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nats.io-jetstream) as a synonym of the tag I created.